# Laravel, как реализовать генерацию меню для всего шаблона за один раз?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

У меня есть шаблон сайта. В шапке сайта меню.

В БД таблица с меню (id, name, description)
И таблица с статичными страницами (id, menu_id, name, position, title, body)

С этим шаблоном работают несколько контроллеров.
Как отображать меню в шапке сайта правильно?

Первоначально подумал делать запрос в бд с получением по нужному меню, нужных страниц. И уже генерировать в blade меню.

Но если контроллеров будет 10? это в каждом одно и тоже.
Не правильным кажется. Нужно как то в одном месте создать генерацию меню для всего шаблона.

Надеюсь я описал понятно свою мысль. Подскажите как нужно сделать?

Для отображения меню мне в шаблон нужно передавать связанные с этим

Comment: Что мешает сделать функцию get_menu и использовать её во всех контроллерах?

Comment: ну я и спрашиваю как правильно это всё сделать) так как я понятия не имею как лучше. Но почему то кажется, что это можно сделать в одном месте и не возвращаться к этому

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы правильно заметили, что дублировать код в данном случае не нужно.

В Laravel есть как минимум три способа сделать это удобнее:

1. С помощью View-компонентов: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components
2. С помощью Laravel Livewire: https://laravel-livewire.com/
3. Сделать API endpoint и самому посылать запросы API запросы, чтобы получить данные и создать меню с помощью AJAX